# Notepad++ Change case only one letter in a few sentences after a certain symbol

Tags: notepad++, regex

There are all lines of this type:

> https://aaa/aaa/aaa/*2018*/*06*/**b**bb_**b**bb-bbb_**b**bb-bbb-1-bbb.doc

It is necessary to change the case of only the first letter in all phrases that are after the last `/` and separated by `_` (marked in bold). Do not touch those near `-` as well as all text up to the last `/`and after the last non-letter character to the end of the line.

I created two options for my case:

1. `\w++(?!.*/)(?!$)`
2. `[^\W_]++(?!.*/)(?!$)`

In the first option, only those near `-` are highlighted.
In the second option, all phrases are already highlighted, near `_` and `-`.
Now we need a third option, which will select only those that are near `_` and others that near `-` did not change. Help please

Comment: Please [edit] and translate the title of the question and remove the Russian text. All questions and answers on [SU] must be in English.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:https://\S+/|\G_)\K[a-z][^_]+`
- Replace with: `\u$0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    https://        # literally
    \S+             # 1 or more non space character
    /               # a slash
  |               # OR
    \G              # restart from last match position
    _               # underscore
)               # end group
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
[a-z]           # a small letter
[^_]+           # 1 or more any character that is not underscore
```

**Replacement:**

```
\u          # uppercase 1rst letter
$0          # the whole match
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]